# Add .gsheets to Spotlight under spreadsheets

Tags: macos, spotlight, google

Currently if I'm searching for something and it happens to be a Google spreadsheet it shows up under other. Is there any way to have .gsheets show up under spreadsheets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that Google spreadsheets aren't classified by Spotlight as spreadsheets is that information is missing from the Info.plist file within the Google Drive application.

For example, in the Info.plist file within the Numbers application bundle Apple define their "numbers" document with the Document Content Type UTIs of `com.apple.iwork.numbers.numbers`. Then further down in the same plist that UTI is then further defined as "Conforms to" amongst other things `public.spreadsheet`. And this is why Spotlight classifies Numbers document as "Spreadsheets".

[image: Document Type for numbers documents]

[image: Exported Type UTI for numbers documents]

However in the Info.plist for Google Drive there is no Document Content Type UTIs for gsheet files at all, and therefore no "Conforms to" either. So Spotlight just treats it as "Other".

[image: Document Type for gsheet documents]

This is something that Google should really fix, and it should be relatively simple for them to do so.

In the meantime there is a possible (albeit slightly hacky) potential fix outlined towards the end of this answer to a question on superuser.com: [OSX: assign extension to content kind](https://superuser.com/questions/371892/osx-assign-extension-to-content-kind/371939#371939)

Comment: Congrats on 1k; your contributions are excellent!